# Compressing a binary matrix

Tags: language-agnostic, binary, matrix, compression

We were asked to find a way to compress a square binary matrix as much as possible, and if possible, to add redundancy bits to check and maybe correct errors.

The redundancy thing is easy to implement in my opinion. The complicated part is compressing the matrix. I thought about using run-length after reshaping the matrix to a vector because there will be more zeros than ones, but I only achieved a 40bits compression (we are working on small sizes) although I thought it'd be better.

Also, after run-length an idea was Huffman coding the matrix, but a dictionary must be sent in order to recover the original information.

I'd like to know what would be the best way to compress a binary matrix?

After reading some comments, yes @Adam you're right, the 14x14 matrix should be compressed in 128bits, so if I only use the coordinates (rows&cols) for each non-zero element, still it would be 160bits (since there are twenty ones). I'm not looking for an exact solution but for a useful idea.

Comment: Compression is highly dependent on the source data. Since you say your matrices are "small sizes", why not post one?

Comment: Here's a hint: You can interpret a "square binary matrix" as a black-and-white image. What image compression methods can you think of? How about ones with redundancy?

Comment: http://nopaste.info/c2e37a5da2.html

would be my demo matrix for instance

Comment: If the matrix is sufficiently sparse a list of zero or non-zero locations would save you quite a bit of storage space.

Comment: @awoodland, that's called a sparse matrix and there's a lot of representations possible. Wikipedia has a good list, but Matlab already comes with a good one, CSC.

Answer (score 6):

You can only talk about compressing something if you have a distribution and a representation. That's the issue of the dictionary you have to send along: you *always* need some sort of dictionary of protocol to uncompress something. It just so happens that things like `.zip` and `.mpeg` already have those dictionaries/codecs. Even something as simple as Huffman-encoding is an algorithm; on the other side of the communication channel (you can think of compression as communication), the other person already has a bit of code (the dictionary) to perform the Huffman decompression scheme.

Thus you cannot even begin to talk about compressing something without first thinking "what kinds of matrices do I expect to see?", "is the data truly random, or is there order?", and if so "how can I represent the matrices to take advantage of order in the data?".

You cannot compress some matrices without increasing the size of other objects (by at least 1 bit). This is bad news if all matrices are equally probable, and you care equally about them all.

**Addenda:**

The answer to use sparse matrix machinery is not necessarily the right answer. The matrix could for example be represented in python as `[[(r+c)%2 for c in range (cols)] for r in range(rows)]` (a checkerboard pattern), and a sparse matrix wouldn't compress it at all, but the Kolmogorov complexity of the matrix is the above program's length.

> Well, I know every matrix will have the same number of ones, so this is kind of deterministic. The only think I don't know is where the 1's will be. Also, if I transmit the matrix with a dictionary and there are burst errors, maybe the dictionary gets affected so... wouldnt be the resulting information corrupted? That's why I was trying to use lossless data compression such as run-length, the decoder just doesnt need a dictionary. --original poster

How many 1s does the matrix have as a fraction of its size, and what is its size (`NxN` -- what is `N`)?

Furthermore, this is an incorrect assertion and should not be used as a reason to desire run-length encoding (which still requires a program); when you transmit data over a channel, you can always add error-correction to this data. "Data" is just a blob of bits. You can transmit both the data and any required dictionaries over the channel. The error-correcting machinery does not care at all what the bits you transmit are for.

**Addendum 2:**

There are `(14*14) choose 20` possible arrangements, which I assume are randomly chosen. If this number was larger than `128^2` what you're trying to do would be impossible. Fortunately `log_2((14*14) choose 20) ~= 90bits < 128bits` so it's possible.

The simple solution of writing down 20 numbers like `32,2,67,175,52,...,168` won't work because `log_2(14*14)*20 ~= 153bits > 128bits`. This would be equivalent to run-length encoding. We want to do something like this but we are on a very strict budget and cannot afford to be "wasteful" with bits.

Because you care about each possibility equally, your "dictionary"/"program" will simulate a giant lookup table. **Matlab's sparse matrix implementation may work but is not guaranteed to work and is thus not a correct solution.**

If you can create a bijection between the number range `[0,2^128)` and subsets of size 20, you're good to go. This corresponds to enumerating ways to descend the pyramid in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient to the 20th element of row 196. This is the same as **enumerating** all "k-combinations". See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Enumerating_k-combinations

Fortunately I know that Mathematica and Sage and other CAS software can apparently generate the "5th" or "12th" or arbitrarily numbered k-subset. Looking through their documentation, we come upon a function called "rank", e.g. http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/sage/combinat/subset.html

So then we do some more searching, and come across some arcane Fortran code like http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/m_src/subset/ksub_rank.m and http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/m_src/subset/ksub_unrank.m

We could reverse-engineer it, but it's kind of dense. But now we have enough information to search for `k-subset rank unrank`, which leads us to  http://www.site.uottawa.ca/~lucia/courses/5165-09/GenCombObj.pdf -- see the section
"Generating k-subsets (of an n-set): Lexicographical
Ordering" and the `rank` and `unrank` algorithms on the next few pages.

In order to achieve the exact theoretically optimal compression, in the case of a uniformly random distribution of 1s, we must thus use this technique to biject our matrices to our output number of range <`2^128`. It just so happens that combinations have a natural ordering, known as ranking and unranking of combinations. You assign a number to each combination (ranking), and if you know the number you automatically know the combination (unranking). Googling `k-subset rank unrank` will probably yield other algorithms.

Thus your solution would look like this:

```
serialize the matrix into a list
    e.g. [[0,0,1][0,1,1][1,0,0]] -> [0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0]
take the indices of the 1s:
    e.g. [0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0] -> [3,5,6,7]
          1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9      a k=4-subset of an n=9 set
take the rank
    e.g. compressed = rank([3,5,6,7], n=9)
         compressed==412 (or something, I made that up)
you're done!
    e.g. 412 -binary-> 110011100 (at most n=9bits, less than 2^n=2^9=512)
to uncompress, unrank it
```

Comment: Well, I know every matrix will have the same number of ones, so this is kind of deterministic. The only think I don't know is where the 1's will be.

Also, if I transmit the matrix with a dictionary and there are burst errors, maybe the dictionary gets affected so... wouldnt be the resulting information corrupted? That's why I was trying to use loseless data compression such as run-length, the decoder just doesnt need a dictionary.

Comment: @ninjagecko sry, I meant loseless "dictionaryless" algorithms

Comment: @anniesboobs: answered as addendum to question

Comment: @ninjadegko @Adam More precisely, we're given where the non-zero elements are. And the matrix will be always 14x14, but we have to compress where the 1's are in less than 128bits (always 20 ones), thing that I find impossible right now. But I think it's easier to compress the entire matrix than the single coordinates of the non-zero elements.

So that's why implemented run-length, but I'm checking sparse matrix on Matlab rigth now. Thank you guys.

Comment: @ninjagecko wow, impressive work you've done. I was thinking in compressing the distance between ones on each row, but this is amazing. Thank you soooo much, I'm going to try to implement it right now :D

Comment: this **is** compressing the distance between 1s =) (just not on each row). no problem, make sure you can explain the answer! the key is that you are finding the bijection between exactly the matrices you care about and an output number

Answer (score 4):

I'll get to 128 bits in a sec, first here's how you fit a 14x14 boolean matrix with exactly 20 nonzeros into 136 bits. It's based on the CSC sparse matrix format.

You have an array `c` with 14 4-bit counters that tell you how many nonzeros are in each column.
You have another array `r` with 20 4-bit row indices.

> 56 bits (c) + 80 bits (r) = 136 bits.

Let's squeeze 8 bits out of `c`:
Instead of 4-bit counters, use 2-bit. `c` is now 2*14 = 28 bits, but can't support more than 3 nonzeros per column. This leaves us with 128-80-28 = 20 bits. Use that space for array `a4c` with 5 4-bit elements that "add 4 to an element of c" specified by the 4-bit element. So, if `a4c={2,2,10,15, 15}` that means `c[2] += 4; c[2] += 4 (again); c[10] += 4;`.

The "most wasteful" distribution of nonzeros is one where the column count will require an add-4 to support 1 extra nonzero: so 5 columns with 4 nonzeros each. Luckily we have exactly 5 add-4s available.

> Total space = 28 bits (c) + 20 bits
>   (a4c) + 80 bits (r) = 128 bits.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's an easy to understand&implement solution @Adam :)

Answer (score 3):

Your input is a perfect candidate for a sparse matrix. You said you're using Matlab, so you already have a good sparse matrix built for you.

```
spm = sparse(dense_matrix)
```

Matlab's sparse matrix implementation uses Compressed Sparse Columns, which has memory usage on the order of `2*(# of nonzeros) + (# of columns)`, which should be pretty good in your case of 20 nonzeros and 14 columns. Storing 20 values sure is better than storing 196...

Also remember that all matrices in Matlab are going to be composed of doubles. Just because your matrix can be stored as a 1-bit boolean doesn't mean Matlab won't stick it into a 64-bit floating point value... If you do need it as a boolean you're going to have to make your own type in C and use .mex files to interface with Matlab.

Comment: while sometimes useful, the poster does not even say the matrix is sparse. the matrix could be  represented in python for example as `[[(r+c)%2 for c in range (cols)] for r in range(rows)]` (a checkerboard pattern), and a sparse matrix wouldn't compress it at all, but the kolmogorov complexity of the matrix is the above program

Comment: @ninjagecko, see the comments to the original question. The poster posts a link to an example 14x14 matrix with 20 nonzeros.

Comment: apologies, in that particular case, a sparse matrix would then be good in such a situation, and your answer is quite good in that it gives the size as a function of some statistics

Answer (score -1):

After thinking about this again, if all your matrices are going to be this small and they're all binary, then just store them as a binary vector (bitmask). Going off your 14x14 example, that requires 196 bits or 25 bytes (plus n, m if your dimensions are not constant). That same vector in Matlab would use 64 bits per element, or 1568 bytes. So storing the matrix as a bitmask takes as much space as 4 elements of the original matrix in Matlab, for a compression ratio of 62x.

Unfortunately I don't know if Matlab supports bitmasks natively or if you have to resort to .mex files. If you do get into C++ you can use STL's `vector<bool>` which implements a bitmask for you.