# Encode boolean adjacency matrix of directed graph in Python

Tags: python, list, encoding, matrix

I have a 2D list of booleans that represents the adjacency matrix of a directed graph in Python. I'm trying to write this matrix to a file, but the matrix itself is quite large so I was trying to come up with some way of encoding it prior to writing it to a file.

I figured I could treat each column as a binary number - so I could convert this to a decimal number and write that to the file. First, however, I would write the number of nodes to ensure that each encodement is unique.

So for example if the matrix was `[[False, True], [True, True]]`, my file would look like this:

> 2 (number of nodes)
>     1 (01 as decimal)
>     3 (11 as decimal)

Of course, without the parenthesized text.

My **question** is: is there another more space-efficient (as in, the resulting file would be smaller) way of encoding this matrix?

Comment: the example you are giving seams quite compact.
If you have either a very connected matrix, or a matrix where very fiew vertices are connected, you could also just store it as an edge list.

Comment: You can change the base, like base64 instead of base 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have some patterns in your data to compress it better.
More patterns = More compression. You make up your data in terms of a pattern.

In case you have a random dataset matrix, you can use the **rank** method to compress it.
Have a good look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6051707/808255)

A good [Paper](http://siam.omnibooksonline.com/2011datamining/data/papers/014.pdf) on the subject

Answer (score 1):

For a graph's adjacency matrix, chances are it's pretty sparse, so simply convert the matrix to a [Scipy sparse matrix](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) and [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) it (no need to devise your own file format).